# android ImageSpan setBounds when use lineSpacingExtra in Textview

Tags: android, html

i want to add ImageSpan in textview and every thing is ok with this code :

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            MyAyehNumber Tag1 = new MyAyehNumber(My_Context, null);

            Tag1.set_tagtitle(Title);

            BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(Tag1);

            int dWidth = bd.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int dHeight = bd.getIntrinsicHeight();



            bd.setBounds(0,0, dWidth,dHeight);


            ImageSpan mImageSpan= new ImageSpan(bd);

            sb.append(contactName);
sb.setSpan(mImageSpan, sb.length()-(contactName.length()),   sb.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
Txt_Ayeh.append(sb);
```

but when i set android:lineSpacingExtra for Textview... ImageSpan is located below of text !
how can set bounds to center ???
tnx

Comment: did you try ImageSpan(Drawable d, int verticalAlignment) ?

Comment: tnx for your comment ! i try this : ImageSpan mImageSpan= new ImageSpan(bd,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); result=little better ! but not good

Comment: if it doesnt help you shoyld peobably extend ReplacementSpan

Comment: can you show me some example please ? or explain more...thanks again

Comment: find sources of  DynamicDrawableSpan.java and see getSize method